# How do you change the link color in a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, colors, hyperlink, uitextfield

Anyone know how to change the link color or the phone number color in a UITextField? It's nice that the detection option automatically changes the color of these things to blue and underlines them. But come on, fluorescent blue? Really? OK, it looks fine on a white background, I guess.

Wishful thinking ...

textField.linkColor = [UIColor notThatAwfulBlue];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can I change the color of auto detected links on UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350423/can-i-change-the-color-of-auto-detected-links-on-uitextview)

For a UITextView, but I guess the solution is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen references to using a webview for various things along these lines. I guess that would work. Thanks again.

Comment: So I found a good example of using a text file (added as a resource to the project) to hold html. I used that to set up basically the whole view. Two issues:

First the view wants to scroll even though the entire content is already visible. it does the usual bounce at the edges. I can live with that but would rather turn that off somehow.

Second, the links don't work in the simulator, argh. But when testing on the device, the autodetected mailto's go to the mail app but the urls want to display the new page right in the same view.

I would rather it went to Safari. Anyone know how to do that?