# Changing hyperlink color in UITextView

Tags: uitextview

I have a simple question. Is it somehow possible to change the color of hyperlinks in an UITextView?

Comment: No, but you can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350423/can-i-change-the-color-of-auto-detected-links-on-uitextview/2451285#2451285