# Change color of UITextView links with a filter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, filter, uitextview

The detected links on a UITextView are always blue. There's no way to directly change this. But can I overlay some sort of filter which changes blue to, for instance, red?

Comment: Nice idea =) What about other text?

Answer (score 6):

There's actually a way to do this **with private API**.

A `UITextView` has a (single) subview of class `UIWebDocumentView`, with the selector `setUserStyleSheet:`.

The following code should change the color of the links to green. At least, it worked for me! :)

```
for (UIView *subview in textView.subviews) {
    [subview setUserStyleSheet:@"a { color: #00FF00; }"];
}
```

I know this is really late, but hours of Googling got me no where, so I thought I'd share this.

Comment: There is no setUserStyleSheet method in UIView, are you sure this is working?

Comment: Of course, it isn't available, because it is private. You need to forward declare it like this:

`@interface UIView (Stylesheet)
- (void) setUserStyleSheet: (NSString *) str;
@end`

Comment: UITextView may have more than one subview, check if subview responses to setUserStyleSheet. 
`for (UIView *subview in textview.subviews) {
        if ([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setUserStyleSheet:)]) {
            [subview performSelector:@selector(setUserStyleSheet:) withObject:@"a { color: #00FF00; }"];
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3):

There's no practical way to do this with a UITextView, what you can try is using a UIWebView changing its 'auto detect links' property and then reformatting the HTML.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webText.delegate = self;
[webView setDataDetectorType:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];

NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><script> document.ontouchmove = function(event) { if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.clientHeight) event.preventDefault(); } </script><style type='text/css'>* { margin:0; padding:0; } p { color:black; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:14px; } a { color:#000000; text-decoration:underline; }</style></head><body><p>%@</p></body></html>", [update objectForKey:@"text"]];

[webText loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Or something closely similar.

Hope this helps.

EDIT

Don't forget to implement the UIWebView delegate for this to work.

Comment: I had thought about doing that, but a UIWebView is really too 'heavy' for my needs, especially since there will be one for each table view cell.

Comment: I reckon this ought to be your best bet, if not your only. I'm really curious to see if there's another solution, which automatically will be better because an UIWebView indeed is too heavy for your cause. (For every cause if you ask me.)

Answer (score 1):

UIwebDocumentView has the missing selector.
Import  UIWebDocumentView.h to get it.
Unfortunately this is a private API, and yourapp may get rejected by Apple :-(