# changing the color of Phone number(UITextView...with detect Phone Number enabled in xib file) in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, uitextview, phone-number

Can we change from default blue color of Phone number(**UITextView...with detect Phone Number option enabled in xib file**) to other color in objective c?

For example number like **00471122345** shown in blue color in app which is not suiting by application back ground.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350423/can-i-change-the-color-of-auto-detected-links-on-uitextview/2451285#2451285

Comment: @ender: maybe you should post this as an answer (since it is) or the SO guys should merge/close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the default text colors in a UITextView.  If you want control over text colors, the best way is to use UIWebView.  It even has built-in detect phone numbers, if you want that.  In a web view, you can change the text color, the background color, the link color, the visited link color, etc. just like on a normal web page.

(You can also do fancy alignment, tabling, add images, put have different parts of text be different size/font/color, etc.  It's just a web page! :)