# UIWebView change color of dataDetectorType links

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, datadetectortypes

I have a UIWebView with a black background and I would like the phone numbers that are auto-detected by dataDectectorType to show in white, but I can't find a way to change it from the default blue.

Has anyone had to deal with this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question was answered here, I think is what you want:

[Can I change the color of auto detected links on UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350423/can-i-change-the-color-of-auto-detected-links-on-uitextview)

Hope this helps.