# UIDataDetectorTypes custom link color?

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, uikit, uitextview

Is it possible to set the color of the links generated by `UIDataDetectorTypes`?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately no.

Your only option is to inherit from `UITextView` and override `DrawRect`, which is pretty cumbersome.

Alternatively you could use a `UIWebView` with a style sheet. See this answer for details:
[Can I change the color of auto detected links on UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350423/can-i-change-the-color-of-auto-detected-links-on-uitextview)
This is however a pretty heavy approach.