# change uitextview hyperlink color

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am using `UITextView` and i want to change the color of hyperlink which i use in this component. For example if `UITextView` is showing *www.gmail.com* then it shows up in blue color. I want to change that color.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

The simple answer is you cannot do it.

Here's a workaround though:

[Can I change the color of auto detected links on UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350423/can-i-change-the-color-of-auto-detected-links-on-uitextview/2451285#2451285)

Answer (score 137):

Huzzah! Apple have released a proper solution with iOS7! As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048561/1202222) you can use the `linkTextAttributes` property of a `UITextView`. A white, underlined link would look something like this:

```
yourTextView.linkTextAttributes = @{
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], 
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
};
```

or alternatively you could change the `tintColor`, since `UITextView` inherits from `UIView` and uses the `tintColor` property to colour links - see:

```
yourTextView.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Now your links can look epic!

Comment: I found a way to fix the cursor issue: yourTextView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(), NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, NSCursorAttributeName: NSCursor.pointingHand()]