# Xcode Text View detection color

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a TextView using white text so it shows up against the dark background image I am using. I want to keep a background image behind this text.The TextView is correctly  responding and phone number on it shows as blue which is hard to see against the background. Is there a way to change the color of these detected phone numbers, links etc?

Comment: Why not use a `UIWebView`? It will provide you [more control in terms of customisation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2451285/1407017).

Comment: why cant you use the delegate to check whether the textView became first responder and then change a background image or the text font color??

Comment: I don't want to use UIWebView because it will leave a 'hole' in the background image where the view sits. By using a Text View and setting its background to 'default' I can have the text appearing on the image which sits behind it.