# How to change color of links detected by UIDataDetector in an UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

How to change the color of a specific `UITextView` link generated by the `UIDataDetector` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 7 you can set the *tintColor* of the `UITextView`. It affects the link color as well as the cursor line and the selected text color.

iOS 7 also added a new property to `UITextView` called `linkTextAttributes` which would appear to let you fully control the link style.

Thanks to @stonemonk in [Can I change the color of auto detected links on UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350423/can-i-change-the-color-of-auto-detected-links-on-uitextview)