# UITextView: make auto-detected phone numbers, addresses, and calendar events use same styling as links?

Tags: ios, uitextview

[Questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350423/can-i-change-the-color-of-auto-detected-links-on-uitextview) and others are similar but don't answer the question.

UITextView can automatically detect and style phone numbers, calendar events, links, and addresses.

However, the phone numbers and addresses look different than links.

How can you ensure all auto-detected data appear the same?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @AndréSlotta will do shortly. Thanks for helping!