# Is there a more customizable way to create embedded hyperlinks?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to create a generalized function/class that builds embedded hyperlinks. I am using an `NSAttributedString` with `NSAttributedString.Key.link` attribute and assigning a URL to the specified range. I can even specify multiple links within the body of text, with specific styles for the text. However the only caveat that I am seeing is that the highlighted state of the links have a grey background color. Is there a way to get rid of this background color, and on top of that assign a specified highlight state color for the link? 
I am open to other means of creating the text and links, but I feel like `NSAttributedString` is the right means.

Again:

- the body of text should be able to handle any number of links
- each link can contain any number of words
- the highlighted state shouldn't have a background color of grey, and be able to accept a specified color for a highlight state
- the text should be able to wrap if needed

Comment: Where are these used? A label, textfield, or textview?

Comment: I'm currently using a `UITextView`, but if there is a better medium to meet those requirements, then I'm open to it. I guess another requirement would be that the text should be able to wrap. I will update the list

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551112/341994 The trick is that you must set the text view's `linkTextAttributes` to an empty dictionary. Now you can set your individual link attributes in the attributed string.

Comment: But if "be able to accept a specified color for a highlight state" is key, then use a web view with your own CSS.

Comment: Don't think that link helps @matt. Need to change the hyperlink color states. I believe that linkTextAttributes affect the rest of the text other than the hyperlink. Additionally I think that using a webview opens up a whole new can of worms doesn't it?

Comment: Well, it opens the same can of worms you already opened. There is no magic way to tell an attributed string what the link attributes should be _after_ being clicked on (or _while_ being clicked on or whatever you're after). That's web view stuff.

Comment: hmm yeah I mean it's not a desirable thing to do, but I need to build according to specs. Ideally it should be designed differently and I do agree this is a web design/paradigm. But wanted to see if something like this was achievable using native components.

Comment: @rm4g3d0n The easiest way would be creating your links using html and converting the html to NSAttributedString. There are four links states, just create a style color for each as needed:

a:link - unvisited link
a:visited - link visited
a:hover - mouses over (not available in iOS)
a:active - when tapped